# Is it possible to know FocusOwner globally (Java)?

Tags: java, swing, focus

Is it possible to know `FocusOwner` globally - which component is focused without attaching to each of them `FocusListener`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`KeyboardFocusManager#getFocusOwner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html).  It's also possible to monitor changes to the focus globally via this class

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is powerful thing:

```
(KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()).addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(evt);
    }
});
```

Now everything is visible what's happening..